# Possible to disable VideoJs scrubbing?

Tags: video.js

Does anybody know if I can disable scrubbing in VideoJs, but still allow seeking by clicking on the timeline? Unfortunately I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Would this writeup be helpful?  https://player.support.brightcove.com/code-samples/brightcove-player-sample-disable-forward-scrubbing.html

Comment: Unfortunately not :-( I am looking for disallow 'dragging' but still allow clicking on the timeline back- and forwards.